# How to reference cordova.js in Visual Studio 2013 webforms project?

Tags: asp.net, cordova, visual-studio-2013, webforms

I am building a web application (using ASP.NET Webforms) that will be used on Android phones (Mobile Chrome). I would like to reference cordova.js in the project to use Camera API.

Could someone please provide me with brief steps on how to build Cordova for Android on Windows 7 machine so that I could reference it in Visual Studio project?

http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/1.5.0/phonegap_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

Thank you

Comment: Not sure from your question if you'll be wanting to exchange data between your phone and a web service elsewhere. If so then I agree with Kenneth Li below. But have you tried adding the Cordova plugin to VS2013 [link](https://www.visualstudio.com/cordova-vs)? The new VS2015 has better integration than VS2013

Answer (score 0):

no! completely wrong idea! well, I had this idea same as you because I'm also an asp.net programmer.

the Api can be used only if the html files are placed inside the Android phone, if you open an aspx file, which is located in the IIS, you lose control of the phone and cannot access the api.

so, what you should do is: For the client side, use html, css, JavaScript to write your program.  For the Server side, build an asmx Web Services for the client to call.

then in the client side, use 'ajax',  'Post' call the webservices, with 'Cors' enabled and with 'json' data type.